# How to create a title and footnote for multiple page in R Programming? in RTF or PDF

Tags: r

```
#Report Section

output<-"D:/R/Reference program for R/Table_EG_chg.doc" # although this is RTF, we can use the

rtf<-RTF(output,width=8.5,height=11,font.size=9,omi=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)) 


addHeader(rtf,title = " Table14.3.2.3.1", subtitle =" Vital Signs - Absolute Values", font.size=9,TOC.level=0)

addTable(rtf,final,font.size=9,row.names=FALSE,NA.string="0",col.justify='L',header.col.justify='L',col.widths=c(1.75,1.5,1.25,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
addTable(rtf,as.data.frame(head(iris)),font.size=10,row.names=FALSE,NA.string="-")
addText(rtf, "\n\n", bold=TRUE, italic=FALSE)

done(rtf) # writes and closes the file
```

`final` is my data frame which i need to print in the RTF output.

This is the code i have used to create the output in RTF. It works fines for first page alone, for the rest of the page output doesn't have  Title and footnotes in all the pages. Please can anyone has done the this method if so please can you send the code...

This is easily done in SAS. I need it in R.
  Any one has answer for this.....

Comment: Have you considered using [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) instead?

Comment: Did any one answer for my question?

Comment: @pascal  Please can you try this..

Comment: @etienne Please can you try this

Comment: Still I dont have answer for this????

Answer (score 0):

Think you are asking the listings where we can do in SAS programming, I have tried using R program and got the outputs. Please find the below code I have used a dummy dataset and applied logics which you need to get the rtf document where we can see titles and footnotes in multiple pages.

```
library(rtf)

final <- data.frame(Subject = c(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006), Country = c("USA","IND","CHN","JPN","SA","EUR"),
                    Age = c(50,60,51,63,73,65), Sex = c("M","F","M","F","M","F"), SBP = c(120,121,119,123,126,128),
                    DBP = c(80,70,75,85,89,71))

final$seq <- rep(seq(1,nrow(final),2),each =2)


rtf<-RTF("Table_EG_chg.rtf",width=11,height=5,font.size=9,omi=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)) 

for ( i in unique(final$seq)){

  new <-  final [final$seq == i , ]

  new$seq <- NULL

  name.width <- max(sapply(names(new), nchar))
  new <- format(new, justify = "centre")


addHeader(rtf,title = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTable14.3.2.3.1", subtitle ="\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tVital Signs - Absolute Values", font.size=9)

addTable(rtf,new,font.size=9,row.names=FALSE,NA.string="0",col.justify='L',header.col.justify='L',col.widths=c(1.75,1.5,1.25,1.5,1.5,1.5))

startParagraph.RTF(rtf)

addText.RTF(rtf,paste("\n","- Vital signs lab values are collected at the day of ICF.\n"))


addText.RTF(rtf,"- Vital signs SBP - systolic blood pressure; DBP - Diastolic blood pressure")

endParagraph.RTF(rtf)

addPageBreak(rtf, width=11,height=5,font.size=9,omi=rep(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))

}
done(rtf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Jaikumar Sorry it took 6 years for a package to come out that can finally do what you want.  At the end of last year, the [reporter](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reporter) package was released.  This package replicates a lot of the functionality of SAS proc report.  It can do dataset listings, just like SAS.  It will repeat titles and footnotes on every page, without having to do anything special.  Here is an example:

```
library(reporter)
library(magrittr)


# Create table
tbl <- create_table(iris) %>% 
  titles("Sample Title for Iris Data") %>% 
  footnotes("My footnote")

# Create report and add table to report
rpt <- create_report("test.rtf", output_type = "RTF") %>% 
  add_content(tbl)


# Write the report
write_report(rpt)
```

It can also print in RTF, PDF, and TXT.  To use PDF, just change the file name and the output_type.